# Excel formula to convert date from dddd mmmm dd, yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert a long date in excel from the format of `dddd mmmm dd, yyyy` **to** `dd/mm/yyyy` using a formula

#### Example:

Convert the following:

```
Tuesday August 23, 2016
```

To:

```
23/08/2016
```

I've tried using substitute and search without any success and as far as I am aware there is no function where I can input as one format and withdraw it as another format, I tried using `=Text(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy")` too but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a load of FIND, LEFT, RIGHT, and MID functions to transform your date to "23 August 2016," and surround that with =DATEVALUE

Comment: Your attempt with =Text(A1, "dd/mm/yyyy") failed because "Tuesday August 23, 2016" is not a proper long date format. Proper long date format is "Tuesday, August 23, 2016" (observe comma after Tuesday). However if you select the cell you will see just short date in formula bar. Is A1 contains the proper date or its a plain text?

Comment: @J.B. Cell A1 contains the a plain text date: Tuesday August 23, 2016

Comment: Just a question, is there a particular reason you NEED VBA to do this (there very well might be). You can get it to display in a different format in the cell by using the Format Cells->Number menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, using @Bathsheba suggestion, I went around this the long way but it works.

Try:

`=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(A1,1+FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),2),MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),1,3),RIGHT(A1,4)))`

Explaination:

- `MID(A1,1+FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1),2)`-This finds the day in `dd` format from the string in `A1`
- `MID(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),1,3)`-Takes the first three letters of the month from the string in `A1`
- `RIGHT(A1,4)`-Takes the year from the string in `A1`

It then takes these values and concatenates them into the format of `dd mmm yyyy`. The `DATEVALUE` then changes this into the correct format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. This works for all dates in you format.

Note: The cell, which this formula lies, should be formatted for short date.

Answer (score 1):

Custom format the cells as `dd/mm/yyyy` and use this formula:

```
=DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))
```

or without any additional formatting:

```
=TEXT(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)),"dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Unbelievable! Two down votes with no explanation. And yet Bathsheeba, above, gives the same advice with an up vote. My formula works. Anybody care to comment? Am I missing something? Did I misread the question?

Comment: I am confused as to why this was downvoted so I upvoted. It can be shortened to something like `=Text( Mid( A1, Find(" ",A1),99),  "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: @Slai Yeah, you're right. I just caught that. Thanks!...and for the up vote. :-)

Comment: I can't try it in Excel, but it worked on Google Sheets without commas `=Text(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",""),"dd/mm/yyyy")` Edit: never mind .. even `=Text(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy")` worked in Google Sheets xD

Comment: @Brian Unfortunately for me the first throws #VALUE and the 2nd option shows `August 23, 2016` and I am unable to change it to any other value using formatting.

Comment: @Ryflex You might just try `VALUE()` for the first one? I get the same error if there is no space before the year. For the second one, do you have additional spaces in the text? I got the same thing when I added a space.

Answer (score 1):

then your dates might need a bit of cleaning :]

```
=Text( Mid( Trim(Clean(A1)), Find(" ", Trim(Clean(A1)) ), 99) * 1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

**Update**

I just noticed the vba tag

```
[a1].NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
[a1] = Split([a1], , 2)(1)        ' "Tuesday August 23, 2016" to "August 23, 2016"
```

Comment: The `TEXT()` function does not convert to `dd/mm/yyyy" when I try it.

Comment: hmm .. then I guess it has to be converted to a number. I added `* 1`. thanks for testing @Brian as i don't have Excel at home to try it

Comment: Yep! If I put `DATEVALUE()` within your `TEXT()` function it works. :-)